# Numerically order a list based on a pattern

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of file names in the form:

```
['comm_1_1.txt', 'comm_1_10.txt', 'comm_1_11.txt', 'comm_1_4.txt', 'comm_1_5.txt', 'comm_1_6.txt']
```

I wonder how to sort this list numerically to obtain the output:

```
['comm_1_1.txt', 'comm_1_4.txt', 'comm_1_5.txt', 'comm_1_6.txt', 'comm_1_10.txt', 'comm_1_11.txt']
```

Answer (score 3):

You should split needed numbers and convert them to `int`

```
ss = ['comm_1_1.txt', 'comm_1_10.txt', 'comm_1_11.txt', 'comm_1_4.txt', 'comm_1_5.txt', 'comm_1_6.txt']

def numeric(i):
    return tuple(map(int, i.replace('.txt', '').split('_')[1:]))

sorted(ss, key=numeric)
# ['comm_1_1.txt', 'comm_1_4.txt', 'comm_1_5.txt', 'comm_1_6.txt', 'comm_1_10.txt', 'comm_1_11.txt']
```

Answer (score 2):

One technique used for this kind of "human sorting" is to split keys to tuples and convert numeric parts to actual numbers:

```
ss = ['comm_1_1.txt', 'comm_1_10.txt', 'comm_1_11.txt', 'comm_1_4.txt', 'comm_1_5.txt', 'comm_1_6.txt']

print(sorted(ss, key=lambda x : map((lambda v: int(v) if "0" <= v[0] <= "9" else v), re.findall("[0-9]+|[^0-9]+", x))))
```

or, more readable

```
def sortval(x):
   if "0" <= x <= "9":
       return int(x)
   else:
       return x

def human_sort_key(x):
   return map(sortval, re.findall("[0-9]+|[^0-9]+", x))

print sorted(ss, key=human_sort_key)
```

the idea is to split between numeric and non-numeric parts and placing the parts in a list after converting the numeric parts to actual numbers (so that `10` comes after `2`).

Lexicographically sorting the lists gives the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think its a best answer, but you can try it out.

```
l = ['comm_1_1.txt', 'comm_1_10.txt', 'comm_1_11.txt', 'comm_1_4.txt', 'comm_1_5.txt', 'comm_1_6.txt'] 

d = {} 

for i in l:
    filen = i.split('.')
    key = filen[0].split('_')
    d[int(key[2])] = i

for key in sorted(d):
       print(d[key])
```